# Writing CUDA program for more than one GPU

Tags: linux, windows, cuda, gpu

I have more than one GPU and want to execute my kernels on them. Is there an API or software that can schedule/manage GPU resources dynamically? Utilizing resources of all available GPUs for the program.
A utility that may periodically report the available resource and my program will launch as many threads to GPUs.

Secondly, I am using Windows+ Visual Studio for my development. I have read that CUDA is supported on Linux. what changes do I need to do in my program?

Comment: AFAIK there is no library that does cross-gpu scheduling out of the box. You'll have to implement that on your own.

Comment: Stackoverflow works better if you stick to one question at a time. Regarding Linux support, assuming your CPU code is cross-platform your GPU code should be fine; the main issue is setting up your build environment (either using an IDE like Eclipse or using Makefiles). Which to choose is a very broad question (way too broad for SO) but a bit of internet searching should help you (it's a generic question, nothing to do with CUDA GPUs). You could check out the CUDA examples (distributed with the Toolkit) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.I'll separate the questions in future. My CPU code is already working in Windows7 + Visual C++. Therefore, I continued development using this platform. .

Comment: Changing the current GPU is as simple as using cudaSetDevice. Perhaps playng a bit with it will make you conclude that you do not need such a tool.

Comment: I know cudaSetDevice() would change the current device and I can use the first or second device according to the selection. will you recommend the same when I have a rack of 4/8 GPUs?

Comment: I asked the question as I did not find answer to this question by Google. Please provide me an answer first and then vote down my question. No one is providing an answer and just voting down .......Should new members stop asking the question?

Comment: If you understood the difference between SMP and NUMA (look these terms up: **symmetric multiprocessing** and **non-uniform memory access**), you would know that there can't be any generic multi-GPU solution -- a great deal of problem-specific knowledge about data sharing, dependencies, and access patterns is absolutely required to make this worthwhile.  (Which is not to say that detecting these characteristics will never be automated, but it isn't yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have more than GPUs and want to execute my kernels on them. Is there an API or software that can schedule/manage GPU resources dynamically.

For arbitrary kernels that you write, there is no API that I am aware of (certainly no CUDA API) that "automatically" makes use of multiple GPUs.  Today's multi-GPU aware programs often use a strategy like this:

1. detect how many GPUs are available
2. partition the data set into chunks based on the number of GPUs available
3. successively transfer the chunks to each GPU, and launch the computation kernel on each GPU, switching GPUs using `cudaSetDevice()`.

A program that follows the above approach, approximately, is the [cuda simpleMultiGPU sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-multi-gpu).  Once you have worked out the methodology for 2 GPUs, it's not much additional effort to go to 4 or 8 GPUs.  This of course assumes your work is already separable and the data/algorithm partitioning work is "done".

I think this is an area of active research in many places, so if you do a google search you may turn up papers like [this one](http://www.utdallas.edu/~cxl137330/courses/spring14/AdvRTS/protected/slides/23.pdf) or [this one](http://www.ssrg.ece.vt.edu/theses/lyerly14-ms.pdf).  Whether these are of interest to you will probably depend on your exact needs.

There are some new developments with *CUDA libraries* available with CUDA 6 that can perform certain specific operations (e.g. BLAS, FFT) "automatically" using multiple GPUs.  To investigate this further, review the relevant [CUBLAS XT documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#using-the-cublasXt-api) and [CUFFT XT multi-GPU documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#multiple-GPU) and [sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#threed-complex-to-complex-xt-transforms).  As far as I know, at the current time, these operations are limited to 2 GPUs for automatic work distribution.  And these allow for automatic distribution of specific workloads (BLAS, FFT) not arbitrary kernels.

> Secondly, I am using Windows+ Visual Studio for my development. I have read that CUDA is supported on Linux. what changes do I need to do in my program?

With the exception of the [OGL/DX interop APIs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#axzz328NgV2ld) CUDA is mostly orthogonal to choice of windows or linux as a platform.  The typical IDE's are different (windows: [nsight Visual Studio edition](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition), Linux: [nsight eclipse edition](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html#axzz328NgV2ld))  but your code changes will mostly consist of ordinary porting differences between windows and linux.  If you want to get started with linux, follow the [getting started document](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#axzz328NgV2ld).